# How to reposition an undirected weighted graph on a 2D grid where strongly connected nodes stay together?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, square-grid

I have an undirected fully-connected weighted graph of $n$ nodes, where $n=m\times m$. I want to visualize this graph on an $m$ x $m$ 2D grid. My goal is to place nodes connected with edges of higher weights together so that the placement maximizes the sum of weights of edges between neighboring nodes.

For example, if the nodes are human and the weights represent their similarity, I want to place the similar persons together as a group in the 2D grids. Therefore, the placement maximizes the mutual interest/correlations among the neighboring persons (nodes).

For example: [image: graph in spring layout] In the first figure, the graph is visualized in a Spring layout. If I place the nodes in a 2D grid randomly it looks like the following: [image: random]
However, the optimal solution should be as follows: [image: optimal]

Comment: What have you tried? Here is a simple approximation algorithm. Put the nodes randomly. Then for any pair of nodes. if swapping them increases the sum, swap them. Repeat as long as possible.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing

Comment: Thanks, @JohnL. It works for some level of accuracy.